# How to change content outside jQuery UI dialog from dialog?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

I have a dialog box which pops up on selecting a certain span. Now this dialog contains a textarea (hence editable). On clicking the Save button, I need to copy the textarea content to a table cell outside the dialog. That does not seem to be happening. Infact on adding the second line of code in Save function, the dialog box does not popup ! (Using this in WordPress just in case it makes a difference)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("td > span").click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var message = "message" + id;
        var content = jQuery("#" + message).text();
        var $dialog = $("<div></div>").html("<textarea style='width:99%; height:90%' class='popup-content'>" + content + "</textarea>").dialog({
            height: 400,
            width: 400,
            title: 'My Data',
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            dialogClass: 'wp-dialog',
            buttons: {
                "Save": function () {
                    var popup - content = $(".popup-content").val();
                }
            }
        });
        $dialog.dialog("open");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The save button no longer works because `var popup - content` is not valid javascript. If the have the ability, I would first suggest adding some JSLint or JSHint functionality to your editor.

Now, to accomplish what you want to accomplish, it should be rather simple. We'll ignore some potential landmines and assume you have your classes unique identified, but your save function should look something like this:

```
function() {
    $(".my-table-cell").html($(".popup-content").val());
}
```

Comment: What you suggested works perfectly well ! But could you pls elaborate a bit why 'var popup - content is not valid javascript'. Did not get that part.

Comment: It's simply illegal code, the Javascript parser won't understand that syntax. It's the same reason you just can't smash your face against the keyboard and expect the Javascript engine to understand anything.

Comment: Ohh got it. There is a space to the left and right of hyphen...you meant that right ? Horrible mistake. Something went wrong in pasting the code here I guess. But if that's the case I wonder why it wasn't working locally. Neway, thanx !